# Regex to find comments with a word inside them

Tags: python, regex

I have the next regex:

```
comment_pattern = "(/\*[\w\W]*\*/)"
```

With it I am able to search match strings like bellow:

```
/*
blablabla example 
blabla
*/
```

Basically I would also like to search in those comments for the variable Compiler_Warning -> in case its inside a multiline comment to get all the expression-> Can some one tell me how to get it.
Basically my regex should return a match for :

```
/* blabla
Compiler_Warning blablalba
*/
```

But not for the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEPDf7/1)):

```py
import re

text = """\
/*
blablabla example 
blabla
*/

Not comment

/* blabla
Compiler_Warning blablalba
*/"""

pat = re.compile(r"/\*(?=(?:(?!\*/).)*?Compiler_Warning).*?\*/", flags=re.S)

for comment in pat.findall(text):
    print(comment)
```

Prints:

```
/* blabla
Compiler_Warning blablalba
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and for advices

Comment: Not sure why using this outer positive lookahead, [seems to work without](https://regex101.com/r/9giiaW/1) too!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to cross matching `/*` and `*/` in between the start and ending in your examples:

```
(?s)/\*(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*?\bCompiler_Warning\b(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*\*/
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` Inline modifier to have the dot also match a newline
- `/\*` Match `/*`
- `(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*?` Match any character if not directly followed by `*/` or `/*`
- `\bCompiler_Warning\b` Match literally between word boundaries
- `(?:(?!\*/|/\*).)*` Match any character if not directly followed by `*/` or `/*`
- `\*/` Match `*/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pfnAKM/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MGdpkI)